# Unit Testing an Xml format function

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, xml-parsing, nunit

I'm trying to create a unit test for `xml.Format` function, but I can't seem to acquire `customerName` value, I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Please enlighten me.

```
[Test]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Format()
        {
            var script = "var xml = $Xml.Parse('<Customer><Name>John</Name></Customer>');  $Probe.SetValue('a', xml.Format('<p>Hello {{Customer/Name}}!</p>') + '');";
            var probe = await this.SaveProcessAsync("", script, "");

            // ensure our proxy is called
            Assert.AreEqual("<p>Hello John!</p>", probe.GetValue("a"));
        }
```

This is NUnit output,

Expected: `Hello John!`

But was: `"Hello !"`

Comment: The unit test tells you that you have an issue in your production code. Find out why it didn't replace {{Customer/Name}} with John.

Comment: what is `Probe`? And what should `Customer/Name` return? Apart from this you have `probe` and `Probe`. Which one is the corrent one?

Comment: probe is there to execute the script, and there are no 2 probes, one of them is in the script and one of them is an object  in C#. And Customer/Name should obviously return <Name> under <Customer> which is John , I dont quite understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you do this

```
xml.Format('<p>Hello {{Customer/Name}}!</p>')
```

It goes into root which is customer, then tries to find name under customer.Since there is none, it returns null.

Because it already checks the first root it finds, I simply deleted *Customer/* and it worked correctly.

```
xml.Format('<p>Hello {{Name}}!</p>')
```

The result is : 

Hello John!